# Azure Billing Usage API Aggregate functionality is not working

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I am using Azure billing API (Resource Usage-Preview) for getting the consumption data for an Azure subscription and trying to get the aggregated data of particular dates on daily basis. As per the documentation, I am sending showDetails parameter as false while calling API which defines the data should be aggregated, but not able to get aggregated data. In order to make sure the issue I stored data in database and found duplicate entries for the same subscriptionId, meterId, usageStartTime and usageEndTime which seems not correct and also irrespective of the value of showDetails (true or false) parameter I am getting same number of records which all are not aggregated.

Url which i am using : 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/My SubscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=2016-03-02+00%3a00%3a00Z&reportedEndTime=2016-03-03+00%3a00%3a00Z&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=false

Does anyone has faced the same issue or have any idea on this please?

Comment: Can you share the exact data (querystring parameters) you're sending?

Comment: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=2016-03-02+00%3a00%3a00Z&reportedEndTime=2016-03-03+00%3a00%3a00Z&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=false

Comment: Are you using the C# SDK, Azure PowerShell or just REST API for this purpose?

Comment: I am using just REST API